# extracting json using yajl or ijson

Tags: python, json

I'm new to JSON and I am trying to to explore an enormous (16GB) JSON file that I cannot load into memory. Can I get the first entry of the JSON array easily using something like `ijson` or `yajl` in python?

What seems to have worked best so far is the following:

```
parsed = ijson.parse(open("file.json"))
for f in parsed:
    print f
```

The problem is that the output is a whole big mess of lines that I cannot easily put back together into a JSON entry. I am still at a loss about how to get from here to an actual JSON entry. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the structure of the JSON you could dynamically build it at parse time. I had this problem when parsing around 3 gb of json. It's not pretty but it worked.

So, each object had an url, a body, a doc_id and a title. For each parsed item (prefix) i determine what kind it is and noted that we have it with a bool. When all are found i add it to an array which eventually will contain all the objects that were in the JSON.

```
result = []
u = False
b = False
i = False
t = False
for prefix, event, value in ijson.parse(open("./docs.txt", "rb")):
    if(prefix == 'item.url'):
        url = value
        u = True
    elif(prefix == 'item.body'):
        body = value
        b = True
    elif(prefix =='item.doc_id'):
        doc_id = value
        i = True
    elif(prefix == 'item.title'):
        title = value
        t = True
    if u and b and i and t:
        numofDocs = numofDocs +1
        u = False
        b = False
        i = False
        t = False
        result.append({'doc_id': doc_id, 'url': url, 'title' : title, 'body' : body})
```